# embed php in html page in windows webmatrix2 server

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, web-config

I am trying to embed php code in my html pages on my godaddy linux hosted site.
I am aware of howtos that will instruct me how to do this on godaddy by editing my
.htaccess file.

My problem is that I want to develop **locally under windows webmatrix2.**

What needs to be done under a windows server running iis or webmatrix as server?
 My godaddy account is hosted under linux but I develop under windows using webmatrix.

Solutions I have found that don't work.

1) According to one source add these lines to the **applicationhost.config** file

```
<add name="PHP53_via_FastCGI_html" path="*.html" 
   verb="GET,HEAD,POST" modules="FastCgiModule" 
   scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files (x86)\iis express\PHP\v5.3\php-cgi.exe"
   resourceType="Either" />
```

under the iisexpress directory. They crash my entire local site.

2)  In Webmatrix, In the **web.config** file for the site add in this rewrite rule.

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="REWRITE_TO_PHP">
        <match url=".html" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" />

        <action type="Rewrite" url=".php" />
            </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
... more code
```

3) or try this in **web.config**

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>

        <rule name="REWRITE_TO_PHP">
        <match url="*.html" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{"*.Php"} />

    </rule>
</rewrite>
```

4) or  try this in **web.config**

```
<handlers>
<add name="html via php cgi" path="*.html" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" 
scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files\Php\php-cgi.exe" 
resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
```

None of the above work for me.
I know all of the above this is a lot of information. This is all I have been able to find in lengthy web searches. I am not a system coder by experience. I just need something
that works that will allow me to start coding php in html on windows. The key breakthrough
will be if I start seeing my php displying in keyword colors and have webtrix intellisense
work! **Intellisense is great!**
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

**Solution:** Create a *web.config* file in the root directory of your web site with the following code:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="GeneralRewrite" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*).html$" ignoreCase="true" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{tolower:{R:1}}.php" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hi Patrick, The code in your post did not work for me. The test of a solution for what I want to do would be to put the following code in my index.html file. <?php phpinfo(); ?> Upon running the site it would produce the usual phpinfo() information. Thanks for your interest and help. Joe

Answer (score 0):

In your web.config file you should have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="PHP_via_FastCG1" path="*.htm" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\PHP5.5\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" />
        <add name="PHP_via_FastCG2" path="*.html" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\PHP5.5\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Where scriptProcessor="C:\PHP5.5\php-cgi.exe" is determined by where your php is actually stored on the system. You can use phpinfo() for some hints on where this might be for your system.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I think that what you want to do works only on apache not with webmatrix. For further information please read this: [Php tags in .html files don't work in WebMatrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029824/php-tags-in-html-files-dont-work-in-webmatrix)

Comment: This answer needs some improvement. Please provide the relevant information from the link provided.