# Php tags in .html files don't work in WebMatrix

Tags: php, html, file, tags, webmatrix

I've been learning web development and the book I am learning from is using php tags within html files but they don't work for me, here is my header page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title><?php echo $page_title; ?></title>
    <style type="text/css" media="all">@import "./includes/layout.css";</style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="index.php" class="logo"> <img src="Includes/Images/NameIconSplash.png" /></a>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="news">
                <div id="nav">
                    <ul>
                        // Tags don't work here
                        <?php
                            if ( (isset($_COOKIE['user_id'])) && (!strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'logout.php')) ) 
                            {
                                echo '<li><a href="logout.php">                                           Logout</a></li>'
                            } 
                            else 
                            {
                                echo '<li><a href="login.php">                                            Login</a></li>'
                                echo '<li><a href="register.php">                                         Register</a></li>'
                            }
                        ?>




                    </ul>
                </div>
```

The php code is just normal black text but it recognises the html code within the php tags. Does someone know why it doesn't recognise them?

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Is the above file a `.php` file ? And you are running this on a local server, right?

Comment: No it's a .html file, and yes it's a local server.

Comment: You can't use php code in .html file you must give .php extention

Comment: @sandip You _can_ use it.. But your server must be configured to detect it

Comment: Weird because the file in the book is a .html file and has .php code in it and apparently it works for him. I've tried renaming my header file to .php and it displays it ok in WebMatrix, but when I include it in my pages I get an error. I guess I'll have to have two headers, one for html and one for php. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change file extention from .html to .php

Comment: Did that and changed the echo code to pure html outside of php tags and it works. :D

Answer (score 1):

Web servers are configured to detect the file type by looking at the extension. By default it will route .php files through the PHP interpreter, and .html files will be served directly to the end user. You can configure this behaviour via the server's config file, or the local .htaccess file for the individual web directory.

```
RemoveHandler .html .htm
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
```

Do this if you really don't want to save your files as `.php`. Or else saving your files with .php does the job

Comment: @SalmanA Yeah.. Sorry, forgot to mention that.. This will work only with apache

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use php code you have to use .php extension, so change extension to .php.

Comment: Yes you are right, but the way he want to use, it is not possible, for that he has to use code as per your answer.